# Base Url without Request object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8

As per my code, I need to do some caching at the application start and it takes time. So I thought of using IIS "preload enabled" feature. I read it that in case - IIS makes a fake request to the website.

Now, I have 2 confusions:

1. it is true , as IIS restarts , my application receives  application start event in global.ascx -  `protected void Application_Start()`, but I don't have Request object there (it is null). I need the base url of my application to process something, any help how can I have it without Request object
2. Why Request object is null ? if IIs is making a fake request ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's correct, the Request object is not available there because that's not part of a request, that's only the application starting up which is automatically triggered if the application has not started and a request is detected.

There's a another method, `void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)` which might be what you are looking for. This of course runs on every request, but I'm sure you can setup some conditions for whatever you want to do to only run once.

Note that not everything will be available there either, so there yet another method, `protected void Application_AcquireRequestState()` that you can try out as well.

Comment: Preaload , does not raise Begin and AcquireRequestState event :(

Answer (score -1):

You can try using:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
```

It is not related to the request.

Comment: I tried - but it says- "Cannot obtain fields or call methods on the instance of type 'System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost' because it is a proxy to a remote object"

Comment: Try 'HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath'

Comment: using -'HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath' I can find virtual path. But I would need - Url.Scheme (http or https) also, because on prod it will be https..

Comment: The scheme is determined by the request so that won't work. Sounds strange though that you would let the scheme determine what you do in the application startup. Maybe explain closer in your post what you want to achieve.

Comment: I would setup project configurations, for example Dev and Release. Depending on which configuration is compiled, do different stuff in Application_Start. You can setup preprocessor definitions per configuration in your project settings and you could use for example '#if RELEASE' and '#if DEV'.